# Which XML namespaces are declared by default?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

Which XML namespaces are declared by default and need not/must not be declared?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, how about `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`, for instance?

Comment: If you read http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace (convenient, having a web page at the same location), you'll note that it's described as unique.

Comment: Related: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#xmlReserved

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nope, that's not the only one. :)

Comment: Hmm. I knew about that one (forgot about it when writing my answer), but whichever other you've found is news to me.

Comment: Oh, `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

- `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` with prefix `xml`
- `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` with prefix `xmlns`

---

Both the [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl) and the [Namespaces in XML 1.1 (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#ns-decl) define only two namespaces:

> **Namespace constraint: Reserved Prefixes and Namespace Names**
>
> The prefix **xml** is by definition bound to the namespace name
>   `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. It MAY, but need not, be
>   declared, and MUST NOT be undeclared or bound to any other namespace
>   name. Other prefixes MUST NOT be bound to this namespace name, and it
>   MUST NOT be declared as the default namespace.
>
> The prefix **xmlns** is used only to declare namespace bindings and is
>   by definition bound to the namespace name
>   `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`. It *MUST NOT* be declared or
>   undeclared. Other prefixes *MUST NOT* be bound to this namespace name,
>   and it *MUST NOT* be declared as the default namespace. Element names
>   *MUST NOT* have the prefix `xmlns`.
>
> All other prefixes beginning with the three-letter sequence x, m, l,
>   in any case combination, are reserved. This means that:
>
> - users *SHOULD NOT* use them except as defined by later specifications
> - processors *MUST NOT* treat them as fatal errors.

So, only `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` (with prefix `xml`, containing a handful of attributes such as `xml:lang`, [see full list here](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace)), and `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` (with prefix `xmlns`, for declaring other namespaces) are actually defined in the standard.

Some XML processing libraries may elevate `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` (with prefix `xs`) and `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` (with prefix `xsi`) to nearly default status, and even write `xmlns` declarations for these namespaces out by default when writing an XML file, but that is merely convention and not to be relied upon as standard behaviour.

Comment: The answer is correct for namespaces that are implicitly declared within an XML document. In other specs the situation is slightly different. For example, in the XDM data model used by XPath/XSLT/XQuery, every node has "xml" as a namespace binding, but not "xmlns".